# APEX: How to find index of a list using partial text?

Tags: apex, trigger, list

I have a very common requirement yet I am unable to find articles online. Requirement is - I want to find index (position) of an element in the list using partial text search for instance this code -
Here I am trying to find HELLOMYBOSS index from the list but with partial text search.

```
List<string> ss = new List<string>();
ss.add('HELLOMYBOSS');
System.debug(ss.indexof('HELLOMY*')); not working, gives -1
```

Comment: Just find the index of `HELLOMY`. Index searches are looking for literal text so the `*` would be considered a literal character not a wildcard and is not required. If you needed to find multiple fragments like in `HELL*BO*`, split this into an array at the `*`, discarding these separators, and simply iterate and use `indexOf(substring, index)` passing in the ending of the previous match in each iteration to require an ordered matching of each part.

Comment: BTW, you would have to iterate through the list of inputs trying to match each entry. NB: another option would be to try regex matching, against each input.